# MidiManager.getDevices() returns an empty list on Android emulators

Tags: android, emulation, midi

I want to use `MIDI` via `android.media.midi.MidiManager`, however, when I call `MidiManager.getDevices()`, it only returns an empty list, which means no MIDI device.

I referred to [this page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/midi/package-summary.html).

I use Android emulators included in Android Studio.
I'm wondering if `MidiManager.getDevices()` returns an empty list just because of an emulator. Unfortunately, my device is much older than `android.media.midi.MidiManager` requires.

I expected an Android device had a built-in software `MIDI` device, and that an emulator did as well. Is that wrong? I tried several emulator devices but in vain. And I couldn't find such settings for emulators.

By the way, thank you, guys, for notifying me that I can format my question.
This is my first post and I didn't notice it.

---

Later, I found someone who could help me. And his real device returned 0 MIDI device as well. It seems that there is no build-in device or that a built-in device isn't counted.

Comment: CL., I read questions you linked with. It seems to be different from what I want to know. I want to know why 'MidiManager.getDevices()' returns an empty list. Due to an emulator or any other reason?